# How do I sort two selections by date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts P 
WHERE P.ThreadId = 0
ORDER BY 
    (SELECT MAX(R.Time) 
     FROM Posts R 
     WHERE R.ThreadId = P.Id) DESC
```

This selects all threads and orders them by the time of their last reply. Threads without a reply are always behind threads with replies and in random order. I want this command to also order threads without replies by their creation time intermingled with the other threads.

How can I achieve this?
(Side note: Threads and Replies are using the same table "Post". A thread has the ThreadId 0 while a reply has the ThreadId of a parent post.)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What does "intermingled" mean?  That is not a SQL operation.

Comment: Intermingled means that the creation time of a thread without a reply should be compared to the creation time of the replies of threads with replies. Both creation times whould be ordered together.

If a thread with 0 replies was created 10 seconds ago it should appear in front of a thread whose last reply was 15 seconds ago.

Comment: @user2116060: Consider accepting the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: I thought I am supposed to wait for other replies first but ok, I accepted :) The answer is pretty much perfect and there is probably no room for improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is no element in the subquery fullfilling the condition (ie there is not reply to it) the subquery will return `NULL` thus you have to provide a default value. The function for that is [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), which returns the first non-null value of its arguments.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts P 
WHERE P.ThreadId = 0
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX(R.Time) 
     FROM Posts R 
     WHERE R.ThreadId = P.Id), P.Time) DESC
```

So `Coalesce( _thesubquery_, P.Time)` will return the result of the subquery, if it's not null, or `P.Time` (ie the creation time of the non-answered post) otherwise.

You can also apply the `COALESCE` function just around the `max` instead of the whole subquery. This will lead to the same result

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts P 
WHERE P.ThreadId = 0
ORDER BY 
    (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(R.Time), P.Time)
     FROM Posts R 
     WHERE R.ThreadId = P.Id) DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT p1.*,
       COALESCE(p3.time, p1.time) last_thread_time
FROM posts p1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT MAX(p2.time) time
                    FROM posts p2
                    WHERE p2.thread_id = p1.id ) p3 ON TRUE
WHERE p1.thread_id = 0
ORDER BY COALESCE(p3.time, p1.time);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc1a21abf4b4987a591c5e0536369142